# Another way to call function javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

When I call this code, it does not work.

```
<script language="javascript">
var l1OK_WC = false;
var l2OK_WC = false;
function share()
{
   alert('yo');
}
function getIt_wc()
{
   if(l1OK_WC && 120k_WC)
      window.open('http://google.ca','_self');

   if(!l1OK_WC)
      alert("Message 1");
   else if(!l2OK_WC)
      alert("Message 2");
}
</script>
```

And this in the html.

```
<a class="Style3" href="javascript:getIt_wc();"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XJy0nEq.png" /></a>
```

When I click the button, no message appears. This script works fine in blogger or html sites, but not on wordpress. I am doing this on a wordpress page.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your javascript and HTML is even being included in wordpress? Did you check the `view source` to make sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: After looking at the source code of the page, you are naming the function incorrectly!**

Your function shows on the page as:

```
function get()
{
   if(l1OK_WC &#038;&#038; l2OK_WC)
      window.open('http://google.ca','_self');</p>
<p>   if(!l1OK_WC)
      alert("message 1 (You can enter any message)");
   else if(!l2OK_WC)
      alert("message 2(You can enter any message)");
}
```

You'll notice two errors:

1. It's named `get()` not `getIt_wc()`, so you're calling the wrong function in your `onclick`
2. You have some HTML code in there as well: `&#038;&#038;` and `<p>` and `</p>`

---

**ORIGINAL POST:**

You don't need the `a` tag at all. Just use `onclick` on the image and remove the `a` tag:

```
<img class="Style3" src="http://i.imgur.com/XJy0nEq.png" onclick="getIt_wc()" />
```

To let people know it's clickable, in your stylesheet, add the `cursor` style to `Style3`:

```
.Style3 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: the button is not clickable.

Comment: @user3293279 Please check (and post here) if your javascript and the changed HTML is actually being loaded into the page via Wordpress. (Do a "view source"). Also, what browser are you using? (This is IMPORTANT)

Comment: hi, the page is here: http://ultimatescript.net84.net/wordpress/?page_id=39
thanks a lot for helping. using chrome.

Comment: @user3293279 I am glad to help but I'm not going to visit an unknown link. Could you please post the relevant source of that page (from "view source") either here or at http://pastebin.com/ ? Thanks!

Comment: heres the code http://pastebin.com/FrZP7gfK

Comment: @user3293279 No, I need the result of "view source". So what the browser sees when you go to that URL. The whole page.

Comment: @user3293279 I found the problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: here it is: http://pastebin.com/GT4ZLn3W

Comment: i renamed the get back to getIt_wc - The get was an error. and how to remove html code

Comment: @user3293279 Did you also fix the added-in HTML code? That makes invalid javascript code. After the page loads, type `CTRL+shift+j` (that means, hold the ctrl and shift buttons and type the letter "j"). That will bring up the console in Chrome. Then click the button. You should see any errors there.

Comment: how would you fix the added codes? wordpress automatically changes && to &#038;&#038

Comment: @user3293279 That's because you're using Wordpress incorrectly (don't mean to be harsh). Code should not go into that page content field in the CMS. You should be adding code into the theme templates (located in the theme's folder in `/wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME_FOLDER`. BUT, if you don't have access to that, you can do this: http://www.labnol.org/software/javascript-in-wordpress/19396/

Comment: this is what it says when clicking button: Uncaught ReferenceError: getIt_wc is not defined

Comment: @user3293279 see my comment above.

Comment: What do you do after adding to the theme, and how do you add it?

Comment: @user3293279 The theme should have a `header.php`. In there, you add a `<script` tag that points to a javascript file (you'll create that) which holds your function. For example, `<script src="getit.js"></script>`, then you create `getit.js` and put your javascript code in there and save that file to the same folder as `header.php`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Got it working with the shortcodes.

Comment: @user3293279 since this helped you figure out what was wrong and fox it, please mark as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Cant work. If you call the method **getIt_wc**, the variable **l1OK_WC** is ever call **false**.

You script are confusing and can't never produce a result.